# WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) Local TCP proxy redirection works only after WFPSamplere.exe -clean

Tags: visual-studio, wdk, wfp

I am using WFPsampler to redirect TCP IPV4traffic using the below command.

WFPSampler.exe -s PROXY -l FWPM_LAYER_ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V4 -ipra 192.168.10.52 -iprp 9000 -pra 127.0.0.1 -prp 5050 -v -plspid 9184

The redirection doesn't work until I clean all rules that are enabled by default. I don't want to clean already installed rules, is there any way I can make the proxy work without doing

WFPSampler.exe -clean all

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is WPFSampler? Basically what I want to know is what does it do?

Comment: WFPSampler is a sample application from microsoft that allows to configure proxy callout driver which internally uses WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/trans/WFPSampler